# Python Getting mixed results.

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm still fairly new to python and I'm having a bit of trouble getting a "perfect result" from my script.

Here's my code so far:

```
#import urllib2
#file = urllib2.urlopen('https://server/Gin.txt')
Q = raw_input('Search for: ')

if len(Q) > 0:
        for line in open('Gin.txt'):    #Will be corrected later..
                if Q.lower() in line.lower():
                        print line 

                #print "Found nothing. Did you spell it correct?" ## problem here. 
else:
        os.system('clear')
        print "You didn't type anything. QUITTING!"
```

Now the code is working. It finds what I'm looking for, however if it doesn't find a match.
I want it to print "found nothing..." I have gotten all kinds of results, mix matching false-positive results and so on.. almost all but the desired result. It's probably a piece of cake for most of you, but I'm been on this 8+ hours so now I'm here.

If there's a more optimal/simpler/prettier way to write it, feel free to correct my mistakes. I'm aiming for perfection! So I'm all eyes and ears.
FYI. The **gin.txt** contains just about everything from `!#_'[] 0..9` to capital letters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `for` loop has a `else:` clause. It is executed when you *did not* end the loop early:

```
for line in open('Gin.txt'):    #Will be corrected later..
    if Q.lower() in line.lower():
        print line 
        break
else:
    print "Found nothing. Did you spell it correct?"
```

Note the `break`; by breaking out of the `for` loop, the `else:` suite is *not* executed.

This'll of course stop at the first match. If you need to find multiple matches, your only option is to use some form of a flag variable:

```
found = False
for line in open('Gin.txt'):    #Will be corrected later..
    if Q.lower() in line.lower():
        found = True
        print line 

if not found:
    print "Found nothing. Did you spell it correct?"
```

Comment: (+1) It is worth noting, however, that this is not equivalent to the OP's code if there are multiple matches.

Comment: @Martijn Thanks for your answer. Short and just what I needed.